# How do I concatenate 2 columns in a single cell, even when one column is empty

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub ConcatColumns()

   Do While ActiveCell <> ""  'Loops until the active cell is blank.

      'The "&" must have a space on both sides or it will be
      'treated as a variable type of long integer.

      ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
         ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) & " , " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0)

      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
   Loop

End Sub
```

Above is the code I have.

I want to concatenate columns A & B into column C, with a comma in between.
And if column A/B is empty, column C should not have a comma, but just the value itself.

Comment: So you are trying to create something similar to the Excel formula `=IF(A1="",IF(B1="","",B1),IF(B1="",A1,A1&" , "&B1))` ?

Comment: yeap. It's something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment that you are trying to do something like the Excel formula `=IF(A1="",IF(B1="","",B1),IF(B1="",A1,A1&" , "&B1))`, I suggest you use the following code:

```
Sub ConcatColumns()

    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> "" Or ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value <> ""
        With ActiveCell
            ' IF(A1=""
            If .Offset(0, -1).Value = "" Then
                ' IF(B1=""
                If .Value = "" Then
                    ' ""
                    .Offset(0, 1).Value = ""  ' Shouldn't occur, but let's be safe
                Else
                    ' B1
                    .Offset(0, 1).Value = .Value
                End If
            ' IF(B1=""
            ElseIf .Value = "" Then
                ' A1
                .Offset(0, 1).Value = .Offset(0, -1).Value
            Else
                ' A1&" , "&B1
                .Offset(0, 1).Value = .Offset(0, -1).Value & " , " & .Value
            End If
        End With
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
End Sub
```